# Add text to an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having problems with simple adding text value to an associative array. Here's part of my code

```
if($count > 0){ 
        echo $ns_content->encoded;//test works i see the content
        $itemnode = array ( 
            'imgurl' => $item->imgurl,
            'title' => $item->title,
            'desc' => $item->description,
            'content' => $ns_content->encoded,
            'link' => $item->link,
            'date' => $item->pubDate,
            );
        array_push($feed, $itemnode);
    }
print_r($feed);
```

Just echoing the $ns_content->encoded works,but when i insert the value in the array for later use, it stays empty?? This is also the case for description.
The only thing is they are both multiline text with html tags, can this be the problem???

regards

Comment: Please post an example of the HTML output for each output version (the `echo` and the `print_r`. Please view the HTML source and copy the output from there, then update your question with the output.

Comment: What happens if you use `strval` like that: `'content' => strval($ns_content->encoded),` ?

Comment: adding strval gives me hope ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using `SimpleXML` to access the XML-document. If you want to store the value of a node as string, then you have to cast it to a string (otherwise you only have a reference to a `SimpleXMLElement` instance).

There are three ways of doing that:

```
// strval and (string)-cast call __toString()
$str = strval($item->description); 
$str = (string)$item->description;

// call __toString() directly, might blow up if "$item->description" is no object
$str = $item->description->__toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe `if($count > 0)` not working? did u try putting `print_r` inside `if`?

Answer (score 1):

CDATA? I think sometimes CDATA got in my way when trying to parse feeds.  Try SimpleXML with the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` flag maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is probably being rendered. Try:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($feed, 1) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: hmm, no didn't populate the content. With strval it does like vstm pointed out